# live sass compiler not generating css files

Tags: css, sass, live-sass-compiler

I use **live sass compiler** extension in **vsCode** then generation **css** not worked for me until I save  **main.scss** file.

for example have a project contains this directory

```
+style
 - style.css
 - main.scss
 - dashboard (folder)
  --_sidebar.scss

+index.html
```

if change happened in **_sidebar.scss** nothing happened, but then I save **main.scss** file and generation happened.

its always same and every time I use **live sass compiler** boring me when change SCSS file then again save **main.scss** just to generate CSS file.

I changed live sass compiler setting in **setting.json** to this:

```
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
    {
      "format": "compressed",
      "extensionName": ".css",
      "savePath": "~/../style",
      "savePathSegmentKeys": null,
      "savePathReplaceSegmentsWith": null
    }
  ]
```

but it generate all SCSS files in any folder in my computer and I don't know how to fix it.

I want to generate CSS file every time when change happen in any SCSS file

Comment: I got an answer, I used multi_root directory in VS Code but the package doesn't support multi_root directory..

[According to this answer](https://github.com/ritwickdey/vscode-live-sass-compiler/issues/81)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to let you know, [my maintained fork](https://github.com/glenn2223/vscode-live-sass-compiler) supports multi-root workspaces. if you install that, you can keep your settings/structure the same and it will just work

Answer (score 0):

just change your code in settings.json to this one:

```
{
"liveSassCompile.settings.formats": [
  {
    "format": "expanded",
    "extensionName": ".css",
    "savePath": "/css"
  },
  {
    "format": "compressed",
    "extensionName": ".min.css",
    "savePath": "/css"
  }
],
"liveSassCompile.settings.excludeList": ["**/node_modules/**", ".vscode/**"],
"liveSassCompile.settings.generateMap": true,
"liveSassCompile.settings.autoprefix": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions"]
```

}